# How can DOSBox be tweaked to run in "full screen mode" in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, fullscreen, dosbox

How can I tweak DOSBox to run in "full screed mode" in Windows Vista?

Answer (score 6):

In `dosbox.conf` there is a directive specifically for this called **fullscreen**.

Modify it to say:

```
fullscreen = true
```

then start a new instance of DOSBox.

**Note:** If you do not want the program to open in fullscreen every time, you can simply use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle it.